# Apache Authentication

Tags: apache2, authentication, debian

I configured the authentication on Apache2 with .htaccess and .htpasswd files.
Now my problem is that when I close the browser or the browser tab, remain logged in without me being prompted for credentials .
there is a way for which it if I close the browser after reconnecting me be prompted for your credentials ?

Thanks!

Comment: Your browser will be caching the username / password for authentication, so you'd need to clear the cache on exit. How you do that depends on the browser, or you could try browsing the site in private browsing mode.

Comment: Which browser? If it's Chrome, it's possible you have it running in the background (and so keeping the session alive).